# Org file to RTF conversion by Pandoc without numbering headings

Tags: org-mode, pandoc, rtf

I am trying to convert Org files to the RTF format by using Pandoc.
But it produces numbered headings.

How do I get RTF files with unnumbered headings?

### Example

The Org file

```
* First
** Second
*** Third
**** Fourth
***** Fifth
```

is converted into the following RTF file by
`pandoc -f org -t rtf`:

```
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs36 First\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs32 Second\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs28 Third\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li360 \fi-360 1.\tx360\tab Fourth\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li720 \fi-360 a.\tx360\tab Fifth\sa180\sa180\par}
```

I would like to suppress `1.` and `a.` in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://orgmode.org/guide/Headings-and-sections.html:

> only the first three outline levels will be used as headings. Deeper levels will become itemized lists.

Try changing this with the following option:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:5

* First
** Second
*** Third
**** Fourth
***** Fifth
```